# Как указать коректно путь к файла

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Нужно получить контент из JSON файлов, которые лежат в рахиве.
Как правильно в стрим передать путьк этим файлам, учтывая, что архивы я не распаковываю ?

Сейчас у мепя вот такая ошибка :
"Could not find file 'C:\Users\albuk\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\nbl\webarm.backend\APRF.WebARM.API\07022023143523.json'."

При таком коде:

```
 using (var zipFile = new ZipArchive(command.File.OpenReadStream())) {
            if (zipFile.Entries.Count == 0) {
                throw new Exception("В архиве нет файлов");
            }

            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry f in zipFile.Entries) {
                FileImportResult uploadRes = new FileImportResult
                {
                    FileName = f.FullName
                };

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.FullName))
                {
                    string text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    archive.HandlingReportFiles.Add(new HandlingReportFile
                    {
                        FileName = f.FullName,
                        Content = text
                    });
                    uploadRes.ContentJson = text;
                };
```

Comment: Как это не распаковывая архив вы что-то планируете из него получить? Это как прочитать файл не открывая его. Или написать код на C# не включая комп. Путь к файлу в архиве - это путь к архиву + путь внутри архива, очевидно. В какой строке исключение возникает?

Comment: @aepot исключение в StreamReader. 
Ну значит надо распаковать. Но надо сделать это в потоке или как-либо не захламляя ПК распакованными файлами. Это имелось ввиду :)
Сейчас из ошибки я вижу, что указывается путь не к архиву, а ищется файл в корне проекта.
Но файл (архив) у меня прилетает с фронта.

Comment: @aepot ваш совет помог. Я ткнул галочку :)
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZipArchiveEntry.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open)

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.Open())
{
    string text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```